# Diferencia entre el bserverside con aserverside y serverSide de Datatables

Tags: datatables

Buenas, cual es la diferencia en datatables cuando se pone bserverSide o aServerSide o simplemente serverSide, ya que en un equipo me muestra el resultado del datatable si utilizo el bserverside, pero ya en otro equipo con su propio servidor local, no es necesario poner aserverSide o bServerSide, es suficiente con serverSide,y muestra los resultados, existe alguna diferencia entre esos comandos de datatables o se debe a alguna configuracion en el servidor apache???

Answer (score 1):

Depende de la versión de DataTables que estés utilizando.

`bserverSide` se usaba me parece hasta la versión 1.9. Ahora se usa [serverSide](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide).

Es *posible* que la versión actual siga soportando `bserverSide` por un tema de retrocompatibilidad.

Respecto de `aserverSide` nunca lo había visto. Si acaso existió en una versión anterior, supongo que habrá convergido a `serverSide` también.